# Where is the bug in this function requesting the user to enter a file name through a loop?

Tags: c++, g++, ifstream, cin

The following function runs correctly in Visual C++ but not in G++.

```
void OpenFile(ifstream *input)
{
  string fileName = "";
  while (true) {
    cout << "Enter the filename: ";
    cin >> fileName;
    input->open(fileName.c_str());
    cin.clear();
    if (input->is_open()) break;
    cout << "The filename does not exist. Try again." << endl;
  }
}
```

In `g++`, if the user correctly enters the file name the first time, the program will execute. However, if the user incorrectly enters a file name, the function will prompt the user to enter another attempt, and when the user enters a correct file name on a subsequent attempt the cursor will move to the next line and the program pauses. What is the error? Again, this runs correctly in `Visual C++`.

Comment: May be it's an old compiler. By the way, are you entering any spaces for the wrong input ?

Comment: It's g++ (GCC) 3.4.4. No, I'm not entering any spaces for the wrong input.

Comment: You can use the `ifstream` as a boolean to check if everything is ok, although it might look weird since it's a pointer (`if (*input)`.) Why don't you pass it as a reference?

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `clear` on `input` after a failed `open`?

Comment: Code works for me (g++ 4.6.1), what do you pass to the function for the input argument?

Comment: The code is OK, show us how do you invoke OpenFile and more code after invocation. The problem may be in another part of your code.

Comment: Verified working on g++ 4.4.3, could it be stdlib issue? Maybe the failbit is blocking operations

Comment: Stream objects should be passed by reference instead.

Answer (score 1):

What's the `cin.clear()` supposed to be doing?  It shoud reset any error
state in the input, but hopefully, the input isn't in an error state.
(Otherwise, your trying to open a file without a name.)an undefined file.)

With regards to the varying behavior of the program, I suspect it is
linked to the way the system (or the library) is buffering input.  The
`cin >> fileName` will typically not return until you enter a newline;
it will not, however, remove the newline from the input stream.
Depending on how input is buffered, this could cause it to block
(although I don't think it should).  When trying to loop on prompted
input, it is probably best to use `std::getline`, then extract the
information you need from the line you have read.  (In this case, just
stripping white space at either end would probably be sufficient.)